# Archive only old logs with logback

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

Is it possible to to archive only the old files with the logs?

For example, I need to store logs as text 14 days, and then archive?

Currently used appender:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <file>../log/mylog.log</file>
  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>../log/mylog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
      <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    <maxHistory>50</maxHistory>
  </rollingPolicy>

  <encoder>
    <pattern>%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>

</appender>
```

He archives the files immediately after the change log file.

**slf4j-1.7.2 / logback-1.0.9**

Answer (score 2):

The rolled-over log file is an alias of archived log file in logback so that rolling means means archiving.

> I need to store logs as text 14 days, and then archive

Then don't make a max file limit on rolling policy. However, I don't think it is necessary to make it as text. As far as I know, logback archive the log into .gz format. You can use a bunch of command to directly take a look at those logs in .gz format. For example, zcat, zgrep, you can directly use less to take a look at the gz-format log.

You could write a simple shell program to move 14 days of log from the directory to another place(This is the real archiving). That shell only needs to run once a day by setting a cron job.